# How to implement OOBE complete notification in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to do a win32 implementation of [RegisterWaitUntilOOBECompleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oobenotification/nf-oobenotification-registerwaituntiloobecompleted) API for my app.
The goal is to detect OOBE complete and perform specific operations.

However, I don't quite understand how to implement it in c++ code.
I spent the past 6 hours looking for sample implementation but to no luck.
Can anyone explain how to do it?

> Registers a callback to be called once OOBE (Windows Welcome) has been
> completed.
>
> Syntax C++

```
BOOL RegisterWaitUntilOOBECompleted(   OOBE_COMPLETED_CALLBACK
OOBECompletedCallback,   PVOID                   CallbackContext,  
PVOID                   *WaitHandle );
```

> **Parameters**
>
> ***OOBECompletedCallback***
>
> Pointer to an application-defined callback function that will be
> called upon completion of OOBE. For more information, see
> OOBE_COMPLETED_CALLBACK.
>
> ***CallbackContext***
>
> Pointer to the callback context. This value will be passed to the
> function specified by OOBECompletedCallback. This value can be nulll.
>
> ***WaitHandle***
>
> Pointer to a variable that will receive the handle to the wait
> callback registration.

Comment: It's just a function. `void OobeCompletedCallback(PVOID CallbackContext) { ... }` If it is a member function it must be static. The `CallbackContext` is often the `this` pointer of the class with the static function so you can use it to call member functions.

Comment: how about the WaitHandle? How to use it?

Comment: Use it to call `UnregisterWaitUntilOOBECompleted` as the documentation mentions. "Once the callback function has completed, UnregisterWaitUntilOOBECompleted should be called."

Comment: okay got it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone in the future who might be looking for sample implementation of this API, here's how I did it. This sample code is not intended to compile though.

**Header file**

```
#include "Oobenotification.h"

class MainClass
{
    // put constructor here
    
    // destructor
    ~MainClass();
    
    // OOBE notification
    OOBE_COMPLETED_CALLBACK OOBECompletedCallback;
    PVOID m_OOBEHandle = NULL;


    // receive notification one OOBE complete
    void OOBERegisterNotification();
    static void CALLBACK NotifyOOBEComplete(PVOID CallbackContext);
    
    public:
        Init();
};
```

**CPP file**

```
#include "header.h"

void MainClass::~MainClass()
{
    if (m_OOBEHandle != NULL)
        UnregisterWaitUntilOOBECompleted(m_OOBEHandle);
}

void MainClass::Init()
{
    // register to receive oobe complete notification
    OOBERegisterNotification();
}


void MainClass::OOBERegisterNotification()
{
    OOBECompletedCallback = &NotifyOOBEComplete;
    BOOL bRes = ::RegisterWaitUntilOOBECompleted(OOBECompletedCallback, NULL, &m_OOBEHandle);
    if (!bRes)
    {
        // handle failed registration here
    }
}

void CALLBACK MainClass::NotifyOOBEComplete(PVOID Context)
{// async
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Context);

    // what you want to do after OOBE
}
```